# Recenter a Google map after container changed width

Tags: javascript, google-maps, center

I have a google map set with the Javascript API V3. It's displayed in a div with a dynamic width, as a content pane slides up when we click on a marker.

Everything works fine, but one thing: When the pane slides up, the width of the map is changed, and so the center is displaced to the right (the pane is on the left). It is really inconvienient especially for small resolutions, where you can't even see the center after the pane is open.

I've tried the 'resize' trigger, but it doesn't seem to work... Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Calling `resize` by it self will not acheive what you need.

What you need to do is first (before a resize occurs) get the current center of the map

```
var currCenter = map.getCenter();
```

Then you need to do something like the following, after your div is resized.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
map.setCenter(currCenter);
```

Should do the trick

**UPDATE 2018-05-22**

With a new renderer release in version 3.32 of Maps JavaScript API the resize event is no longer a part of `Map` class.

The documentation states

> When the map is resized, the map center is fixed
>
> - The full-screen control now preserves center.
> - **There is no longer any need to trigger the resize event manually.**

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` doesn't have any effect starting from version 3.32

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't do anything :( ... Got no errors either.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you post some code so we can better help.

Comment: It's very important: get the current center of the map **(before a resize occurs)**

Answer (score 18):

First set a variable for the current center, then use a event listener to detect a resize, and thusly set center.

```
//Get current center
var getCen = map.getCenter();

//Use event listener for resize on window
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
   //Set Center
   map.setCenter(getCen);
});
```

Comment: good answer if the content stays consistently in a certain area of the map, for more responsive design in terms of wherever the map is centered from New York to Paris, the above answer works better (ie: get current center, then after resize, recenter map to the previous center).

Answer (score 7):

omarello does work but I can't upvote it. You probably forgot to refer to the var that defines your center coordinates. All "resize" does is pull the divs current width and height, it does not change anything about the map--yet!

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(39.5, -98.3);

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#fullsize").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#map_canvas").css({ 
            width: '1000px'});
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); 
        map.setCenter(center);
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Hy there try this ;)

On map initialization

```
var currentMapCenter = null; 
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function () {
    currentMapCenter = map.getCenter();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function () {
    if (currentMapCenter) {
    // react here
        map.setCenter(currentMapCenter);
    }
    currentMapCenter = null;
});
```

After this just call when tou want the map resize.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```