# Cross origin when load google map n bootstrap modal

Tags: google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, cross-domain

i have link when user click open google map in bootstrap modal

but the error in console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load javascript:void(0). Cross origin requests
>   are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

any solution??

Comment: Can you post your relevant code (the link and the modal for example). Without it we've got little hope of helping

Comment: thank you i figured the problem and solved it and i don't know how to mark question as resolved

Comment: It needs an answer to help future visitors. You can provide the answer yourself and then click accept on your own answer. I would recommend doing this, answering your own question is absolutely OK and makes the site better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that post helped me so much [Loading Google Map into Bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596136/loading-google-map-into-bootstrap-modal)

the problem is that google map must be initialized after open bootstrap modal