# map not display 100% on my bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1iHUJoyHKV-r7tjUqmHy5mY3cHtK1ULyxPtElN2GLNFA/edit?usp=sharing

the map on my modal not displayed perfectly. I already search the solution on the links : [Showing a Google Map in a modal created with Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742839/showing-a-google-map-in-a-modal-created-with-twitter-bootstrap)
but I cannot implement it because I'm a newbie on google map.

my modal html  :

```
    <div id="locateModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="blue bigger">Please fill the following form fields</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body overflow-visible">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

my javascript :

```
        var myLatlng;
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.905270, 107.645368);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!'
            });
        }
        $('.modal').on('shown', function () {
              google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Help me please...

Comment: Are you directly loading this size on your onload of page or your are using some dive to popup for larger size from smaller one for map.

Comment: i am not able to find map-canvas div in html

Answer (score 0):

There is no div named mapCanvas in your html page. Try adding the mapCanvas div inside your modal-body as shown below. This may be the reason the map is not displayed perfectly. Please check and let me know if it works.

```
<div id="locateModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="blue bigger">Please fill the following form fields</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body overflow-visible">
               <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joyson to completed the html.
but my purpose about the map not displayed 100% on the modal dialog with bootstrap v3. I already fix it by myself with this javascript :

```
        var map;        
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myCenter
        });

        function initialize() {
          var mapProp = {
              center:myCenter,
              zoom: 14,
              draggable: false,
              scrollwheel: false,
              mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
          marker.setMap(map);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

          }); 
        };
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", resizingMap());

        $('#locateModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
           //Must wait until the render of the modal appear, thats why we use the resizeMap and NOT resizingMap!! ;-)
           resizeMap();
        })

        function resizeMap() {
           if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
           setTimeout( function(){resizingMap();} , 400);
        }

        function resizingMap() {
           if(typeof map =="undefined") return;
           var center = map.getCenter();
           google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
           map.setCenter(center); 
        }
```

Thanks for help :)