# Google maps shows gray screen instead of map

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

GoogleMaps is shown as gray box instead of map. And on windows resize it works  correctly.
**On window load maps show like this:**
[image: Screen 1]

**After window resize map works correctly:**
[image: Screen 2]

```
<div style="width:100%; height:400px; padding:0; margin:0; border:3px solid gainsboro; border-radius:3px;">
    <div id="canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;"></div>
 </div>
```

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY"></script>
<script>
 var map;
 var latLong;
 $(window).load(function () {
    latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(47.0303105, 28.815481);
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
         center: latLong,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         zoom: 14
     });
            console.log("Map is ready.")
 });
</script>
```

**PS** *Map is declared in a bootstrap modal div*

Thanks for help.

Comment: Since it is more likely a rendering issue, please give more details on how to replicate or better yet a fiddle or a plunk.

Comment: For me, I forgot to add `zoom` option and it is REQUIRED

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google guys made special event trigger, which I use in this case to prevent gray map:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

You need to call `'resize'` after your map-code complete or even with a  some small delay. Try to insert this trigger right after your line `console.log("Map is ready.")`

Comment: Thanks for help, I found answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742839/showing-a-google-map-in-a-modal-created-with-twitter-bootstrap